# Lib-GDX GWT build will not load without Flash on some browsers

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to load my LibGDX application. Using *Firefox without Flash* on a  freshly installed *Ubuntu* system, it does not load.

---

I get this printed in the console:

```
SoundManager: No Flash detected. Trying HTML5-only mode. soundmanager2-jsmin.js:32:357
SoundManager V2.97a.20130512 (AS3/Flash 9) + HTML5 audio soundmanager2-jsmin.js:32:357<br/> SoundManager 2: soundManager: Fatal error: Flash is needed to play some required formats, but is not available. soundmanager2-jsmin.js:32:357
SoundManager 2 HTML5 support: mp3 = false (using flash), mp4 = false (using flash), ogg = true, opus = true, wav = true soundmanager2-jsmin.js:32:357
soundManager: No Flash response within expected time. Likely causes: Flash blocked or JS-Flash security error. soundmanager2-jsmin.js:32:357
soundManager: Waiting indefinitely for Flash (will recover if unblocked)...
```

And this on my screen:

[image: Screen turns white and displays "SoundManager: false"]

I am assuming this is because of the lack of Flash and the fact that these audio formats are not supported in this version of Firefox. However, I am not using **any** audio in my game at all.

In my LibGDX HtmlLauncher, I have:

```
public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
    GwtApplicationConfiguration config 
        = new GwtApplicationConfiguration(getWindowInnerWidth(), getWindowInnerHeight());
    config.preferFlash = false;
    return config;
}
```

This did not fix anything. I am on the latest version of LibGDX, and the latest GWT SDK version. *How do I fix this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out the browser was just too old. With such an old browser, it cannot play mp3s without flash, which it crashes. You can see the github issue I made for more details: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4590